# How to mock useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my component

```
const pinnedLocations = useSelector((state) => state.page.pinnedLocations);
const User = useSelector((state) => state.user);
```

In my test file

```
import store from '../redux/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import LocationHistory from 'Components/location-history';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Location component', () => {
    test('Renders component',  () => {
        const { container, getByText } = render(<LocationHistory />);
        const title = getByText('Location Pattern');
        expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

How to mock both state from useSelector so I can use it on my test file?

Comment: What are you trying to test? Is the issue that the `useSelector` hook needs a redux context provided to it? You may find this helpful: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#setting-up-a-reusable-test-render-function

Comment: @DrewReese I need to get access to both of the state in order to render my component properly

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Directly accessing internal state goes directly against what using RTL is designed for. Why do you need to access internals to render the component properly?

Comment: I need to get the User data, because it is returning ```const accent = accents[User.accent_color];``` error => TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accent_color'). And also I need to get the data from the pinnedLocation. I'm still figuring out how to mock those two states

Comment: You just need to wrap the component you are testing in a `Provider` component and pass an instantiated store object with the state the component is selecting. The link in my first comment shares an example from the redux docs.